# fs full extent R graphics device

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I am starting to explore the sf package and have a question about geom_sf(). All
of my spatial plots render nicely filling the complete R plotting device, however, when
I use geom_sf() in ggplot2 it renders the shapefile in the middle and having a lot of
white space above and below the plot.
Is there an argument inside geom_sf() to make the shapefile fit the entire R window device?

See pic below:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)
nc <- sf::st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package = "sf"), quiet = TRUE)
ggplot(nc) + geom_sf(size = 0.05)
```

[image]

Comment: It looks like the image is as large as it can be, while maintaining the original aspect ratio.

Comment: I understand, but any other shapefile that I import into R fill the entire screen. This only happens when using geom_sf(). For example, qmap from ggmap has an option to either get the plot life geom_sf() or to get the full screen by using extent = 'panel'

Comment: Your other shapefiles probably have an aspect ratio closer to what your windows device is. Even the example shows white space above and below the plot... https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/ggsf.html

Comment: `geom_sf` automatically adds `coord_sf`, which is why you get this. What do you want instead? A distorted map? A longer y-axis?